# ( Trigger) I want to how create trigger in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a project in Mysql

I have a three tables :

First table is `tbl_stock` have some column :

```
stock_id
goods_id
quantity
salePrice
```

Second table is `tbl_purchase` have some column :

```
purchase_id
invoice_id
customer_id
unitPrice
qty
```

3rd table is `tbl_sale` have some column :

```
sale_id
invoice_id
customer_id
unitPrice
qty
```

I want to Create trigger for my database.
when I buy any items and insert record in my database

the ( qty ) in `tbl_purchase pluse` ( quantity ) in tbl_stock
and

when I sell any items

the ( qty ) in `tbl_sale` minus( quantity ) in tbl_stock

thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Triggers aren't complex and are well documented https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html and elsewhere , can you post what you have tried and explain what problem(s) you encountered. NB Triggers are table specific you need triggers on tbl_purchase and tbl_sale , personally I would merge tbl_purchase and tbl_sale into a single table and have a column to define purchase or sale..